# xcode = I sended data from one view to the other, with prepareForSegue, but can't send it to another view in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a problem. First I sended information from textfield with prepareForSegue. I sended from WelkomViewController to TableViewController. There I put the data in a NSMutableDictionary. It's a person and his values. Then I put the person in another NSMutableDictionary for multiple persons. In the tableview I create a list with only the full name of all the persons. And with a click on the row I want to give a new view with the details of the person that the client clicked on. But I can't send the data with prepareForSegue it seems.(see image)

What do I do wrong? Thx for every reply!

[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK7DY.png)

Comment: Code should be posted as a formatted text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a dictionary like an array, which doesn't work (obviously). You should not count on a fixed order for [self.personen allKeys], it can change at any point during runtime, which would result in the wrong person being passed along.

You need to use a mutable array as your storage vessel for people names, then address them by the row of the index path.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use `NSmutablearray` to save data of people so make sure that `self.personen` is an `NSmutablearray` then you need just to use `ObjectAtindex` function to get the selected row .

```
vcGevensView.persoon=[self.personen objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```